# Template Class with one and two template arguments

Tags: c++, class, c++11

I'm trying to create an instance of a Class, that uses templates, but with two possible instantiations.

I have this definition of a class SepChaining with one template argument `E`.

```
template <typename E>
class Container {
  ...
}
```

This is my header file.

```
template <typename E>
class SepChaining : public Container<E> {
  ...
```

And in my main.cpp I have the option to do

```
SepChaining<int>* c = nullptr;

c = new SepChaining<int>;
```

and

```
c = new SepChaining<int, 13>;
```

Of course I am getting an error for the second statement, telling me that there are too many template arguments, but I need a way to implement that option too, to create a instance of the class with 2 parameters. I've read about Partial template specialisation, but I'm not really sure how to implement it.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: If you don't pass `SIZE` as a parameter, do you calculate it yourself ? In that case, it might be handled as a default template parameter.

Comment: Yes, if I do not pass it, it is being set to 7. Can you please explain what you mean by default template parameter?

Comment: See Peter K's answer, default template parameters are similar to default function parameters. If the declarations contains ` = DefaultValue`, the actual use does not need to specify a value for that parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define you template like this

```
template <typename E, size_t S = 7>
class SepChaining : public Container<E> {
    ...
}
```

then you can instantiate it as you suggested

```
// use default value for S that is 7
c1 = new SepChaining<ElementType>;
```

and

```
// specify S = SIZE explicitly
c2 = new SepChaining<ElementType, SIZE>;
```

of cause c1 and c2 will have different types unless SIZE is 7

Comment: The last sentence is a bit too strong. They _probably_ have different types, namely whenever `SIZE!=7`. But `SepChaining<ElementType>` and `SepChaining<ElementType, 7>` are in fact the same type.

Comment: That's what I was looking for. I even tried it like that at one point, but it still didn't want to compile correctly. Now I've rechecked all of my code and viola it works!

Comment: @Yakk Sorry, what musical instrument do you mean?

Comment: @Yakk brance means the french is voila =)